# How to store data to a const variable which received from props in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I need to get data to a const variable in function which is received via props for apply some conditions to received data.

First line shows which data sends through props.

```
 import React from 'react'
 import Joke from './Joke'
 function MyInfo(){
     return(
         <dev>
             <Joke data={{question:"What is your name", answer:"My Name is shape"}} />
         </dev>        
    )
  }
  export default MyInfo
```

Then I tried to get data in 'question' the into const variable 'q' from props in Joke file like this.

```
import React from 'react'
function Joke(props){
    const q= {props.data.question}    
    return(
        <dev>
            <h3>Question : {props.data.question}</h3>
            <h3>Answer : {props.data.answer} </h3>
        </dev>
    )
}
export default Joke
```

But this shows an error and I cannot figure out the reason for it.

Comment: Can you show your `<Joke>` component? Is it a class component or function?

Comment: please provide the relevant code and error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the brackets from your const variable.